# How to return a Promise with consequential axios calls?

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to create a function, that will return a Promise and will call another function that will have an `axios.get()` call. Axios.get() calls an API that returns a data with the following structure:

```js
{
  count: 87, //total number of records
  next: '[api_url]/&page=2'//indication if the API has a next page
  previous: null, ////indication if the API has a previous page, if call URL above - it will return [api_url]/&page=1
  results: [...] //10 objects for each call, or remaining for the last page
}
```

Since I know that only 10 results are being returned on every call, I need to check if the returned object has the `next` key, and if it does - make another call and so on, until no more `next`. I need to concatenate all the results and eventually resolve the Promise returned from the main function with all the data.

So I tried something like that:

```js
const fetchResource = async({type, search, page}) {
  const data = {count: 0, results: []}
  const request = await performFetch({type, search, page}, data).then((data) => {
    console.log('data?', data)
  })
  console.log('req', request)
}

const performFetch = async({type, search, page}, result) => {
  const params = {
    page
  }
  if (search) {
    params.search = search
  }

  await axios.get(`${type}/`, {
    params
  }).then(async({data}) => {
    result.results = [...result.results, ...data.results]
    result.count = data.count
    if (data.next) {
      page += 1
      await performFetch({type, search, page}, result)
    } else {
      console.log('result', result)
      return result
    }
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}
```

Now I see that once I call `fetchResourche` all the requests are going out, and in `console.log('result', result)` I do see the concatenated data:

```js
{
  count: 87,
  results: [/*all 87 objects*/]
}
```

But `console.log('data?', data)` and `console.log('req', request)` both print out `undefined`.

Where I return `result`, I tried to return `Promise.resolve(result)` - same result.

And I'm not sure how to return a Promise here, that will resolve once all the API calls are concluded and all the data is received. What am I missing? How do I make it work?

Comment: Not all paths return a result.

Comment: @DaveMeehan What do you mean? Not all of the API calls? They do all return results, I inspected it.

Comment: You are `await`ing and discarding the return value. How is that meant to propagate up the call stack?  This is why you get `undefined`

Comment: Your code is too complicated and you should try to refactor it. Maybe `return await performFetch({type, s...` could work, but I can't tell for sure without debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of observations regarding your code:

- There's no need to mix `async-await` syntax with promise chaining, i.e. `then()` and `catch()` method calls
- Inside `performFetch` function, you need an explicit `return` statement. Currently, the function is implicitly returning a promise that fulfils with the value of `undefined`.

  Key point here is that the `performFetch` function is returning *before* you get the result of http requests to the API.
  It isn't waiting for the result of HTTP requests to be returned before returning.

Following is a simple demo that illustrates how you can make multiple requests and aggregate the data until API has returned all the data.

```js
let counter = 0;

function fakeAPI() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (counter < 5) resolve({ counter: counter++ });
      else             resolve({ done: true });
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function performFetch() {
  const results = [];
  // keep calling the `fakeAPI` function
  // until it returns "{ done = true }"
  while (true) {
    const result = await fakeAPI();
    if (result.done) break;
    else results.push(result);
  }
  return results;
}

performFetch().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

```html
<small>Wait for 5 seconds</small>
```

Your code can be rewritten as shown below:

```
const fetchResource = async ({ type, search, page }) => {
  const data = { count: 0, results: [] };
  const result = await performFetch({ type, search, page }, data);
  console.log(result);
};

const performFetch = async ({ type, search, page }, result) => {
  const params = { page };
  if (search) params.search = search;

  while (true) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${type}/`, { params });
    result.results = [...result.results, ...data.results];
    result.count = data.count;

    if (data.next) page += 1;
    else           return result;
  }
};
```

Ideally, the code that calls the `fetchResource` function should do the error handling in case any of the HTTP request fails.

Comment: I just rewrote my code based on your code snippet. It certainly does work now, though I still have to do some rewriting (like catching exceptions, for example, as you correctly pointed out). Then I saw your edit to my code, I think it's even better than what I rewrote! :-) But alas I'll have to give it a try only tomorrow. But your answer did give me the right direction! Thank you very much, appreciate your help!